# A ListView app keeps closes

Tags: java, android, listview

I've been trying to make a listview app and had followed step-by-step the instruction, it builds successfully but it always closes itself when I try to run it on my phone.

I've tried to search possible similar questions here but nothing seems to match my condition. If my question turns out to be a duplicate, though, please show me the links that may help me get out of this condition.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/item_title"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        String[] listgoal = new String[] {
                "Buku 1",
                "Buku 2",
                "Buku 3",
                "Album 1",
                "Album 2",
                "Album 3",
                "Tiket 1",
                "Tiket 2",
                "Tiket 3"
        };

        final ArrayList<String> listie = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listgoal.length; ++i) {
            listie.add(listgoal[i]);
        }
        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, listie);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                listie.remove(item);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                view.setAlpha(1);
                            }
                        });
            }

        });

    }
    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            String item = getItem(position);
            return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
        }

}
```

logcat

```
11-08 15:13:43.237 229-229/? V/WLAN_PSA: NL MSG, len[048], NL type[0x11] WNI type[0x5050] len[028]
11-08 15:13:48.247 229-229/? V/WLAN_PSA: NL MSG, len[048], NL type[0x11] WNI type[0x5050] len[028]
11-08 15:13:53.258 229-229/? V/WLAN_PSA: NL MSG, len[048], NL type[0x11] WNI type[0x5050] len[028]
11-08 15:13:53.577 21535-21535/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
11-08 15:13:55.357 18351-18351/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
11-08 15:13:55.377 18351-18351/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-08 15:13:55.377 18351-18351/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-08 15:13:55.387 18351-18351/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-08 15:13:55.387 18351-18351/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-08 15:13:55.387 18351-18351/? D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
11-08 15:13:55.417 18351-18351/? D/dalvikvm: Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-08 15:13:55.657 18351-18351/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-08 15:13:55.677 18351-18351/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-08 15:13:55.687 18351-18355/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 98K, 15% free 595K/696K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 7ms
11-08 15:13:58.268 229-229/? V/WLAN_PSA: NL MSG, len[048], NL type[0x11] WNI type[0x5050] len[028]
11-08 15:14:01.907 18381-18381/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
11-08 15:14:01.927 18381-18381/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-08 15:14:01.937 18381-18381/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-08 15:14:01.937 18381-18381/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-08 15:14:01.937 18381-18381/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-08 15:14:01.937 18381-18381/? D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
11-08 15:14:01.977 18381-18381/? D/dalvikvm: Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-08 15:14:02.197 18381-18381/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-08 15:14:02.207 919-7130/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker appid=10140 user=0: from pid 18381
11-08 15:14:02.217 18381-18381/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-08 15:14:02.217 18381-18390/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 15% free 558K/656K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 2ms
11-08 15:14:02.767 18402-18402/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
11-08 15:14:02.787 18402-18402/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-08 15:14:02.787 18402-18402/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
11-08 15:14:02.797 18402-18402/? D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-08 15:14:02.797 18402-18402/? D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
11-08 15:14:02.797 18402-18402/? D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
11-08 15:14:02.847 18402-18402/? D/dalvikvm: Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-08 15:14:03.167 18402-18402/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-08 15:14:03.187 919-1175/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker/.MainActivity} from pid 18402
11-08 15:14:03.217 18402-18402/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-08 15:14:03.217 919-1175/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker for activity com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker/.MainActivity: pid=18418 uid=10140 gids={50140}
11-08 15:14:03.227 18402-18410/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 98K, 15% free 592K/692K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 5ms
11-08 15:14:03.227 18418-18418/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-08 15:14:03.257 18418-18418/? D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication:com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker
11-08 15:14:03.267 18418-18418/? D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
11-08 15:14:03.267 18418-18418/? D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
11-08 15:14:03.277 229-229/? V/WLAN_PSA: NL MSG, len[048], NL type[0x11] WNI type[0x5050] len[028]
11-08 15:14:03.377 18418-18418/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.3.4.04.04.02.113.008_msm8610_LNX.LA.3.5.3.4__release_AU ()
11-08 15:14:03.377 18418-18418/? I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.14
11-08 15:14:03.377 18418-18418/? I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 07/24/14 Thu
11-08 15:14:03.377 18418-18418/? I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: mybranch3933040
11-08 15:14:03.377 18418-18418/? I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.3
11-08 15:14:03.377 18418-18418/? I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE
11-08 15:14:03.377 18418-18418/? I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.3.4.04.04.02.113.008 +  NOTHING
11-08 15:14:03.417 18418-18418/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c0fd58)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker, PID: 18418
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14838) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596) 
11-08 15:14:03.427 18418-18418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-08 15:14:03.437 18418-18418/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18418 SIG: 9
11-08 15:14:03.437 919-1203/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker/.MainActivity
11-08 15:14:03.447 17936-17936/? D/AutotriggerReceiver: [onReceive]  Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 cmp=com.qualcomm.logkit/.autotrigger.AutotriggerReceiver (has extras) }
11-08 15:14:03.447 17936-17936/? D/AutotriggerReceiver: [onReceive] android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED: data_app_crash
11-08 15:14:03.457 919-2897/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker (pid 18418) has died.
11-08 15:14:03.457 919-2895/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{42adec88 u0 com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker/com.tumblr.ulaaidesu.savingtracker.MainActivity}
11-08 15:14:07.878 919-953/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1132 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.interceptKeyBeforeQueueing:4144 com.android.server.wm.InputMonitor.interceptKeyBeforeQueueing:357 com.android.server.input.InputManagerService.interceptKeyBeforeQueueing:1343 dalvik.system.NativeStart.run:-2 
11-08 15:14:07.878 919-919/? V/KeyguardServiceDelegate: onScreenTurnedOn(showListener = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$21@434a8640)
11-08 15:14:07.878 919-953/? I/PowerManagerService: Waking up from sleep...
11-08 15:14:07.898 19313-19313/? D/KeyguardHostView: screen on, mPassword:null
11-08 15:14:07.898 919-1518/? I/QCOM PowerHAL: Got set_interactive hint
11-08 15:14:07.908 216-216/? D/SurfaceFlinger: Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0xb7bb54e0
11-08 15:14:07.908 216-216/? D/qdhwcomposer: hwc_blank: Unblanking display: 0
11-08 15:14:07.918 32665-32665/? D/wpa_supplicant: RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
11-08 15:14:07.918 32665-32665/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
11-08 15:14:07.937 32665-32665/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: survey data missing!
11-08 15:14:07.957 219-945/? V/SRS_Proc: ParamSet string: screen_state=on
11-08 15:14:07.957 219-945/? D/audio_hw_primary: adev_set_parameters: enter: screen_state=on
11-08 15:14:07.957 219-945/? D/audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_set_anc_parameters: anc_enabled:0
11-08 15:14:07.957 219-945/? E/audio_a2dp_hw: adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null
11-08 15:14:07.957 32665-32665/? D/wpa_supplicant: RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=23): 44 52 49 56 45 52 20 53 45 54 53 55 53 50 45 4e 44 4d 4f 44 45 20 30
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your `StableArrayAdapter` class expects your item layout to be just a `TextView`, no surrounding `LinearLayout`. Don't forget to copy the `xmlns:android...` line to the `TextView`.

Comment: thanks! it worked, but toolbar--or the actionbar--is missing. What can I do to get it back?

Comment: That's not really related to this post, so it'll have to be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Adapter requires a TextView to put your array entries, it can not find TextView that is inside any Container such as LinearLayout you have used in your `item_layout.xml`.

To solve your problem you can use one of these solution:

1. You can use standard ArrayAdapter and provide layout name and textview id both with the adapter:

   arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.item_layout,R.id.item_title,myArray);
2. Or you can provide TextView as a main view in your item_layout.xml file.